# Confusion about mySQL that comes with XAMPP

Tags: mysql, database, xampp, web-development-server

Can I use mySQL that came bundled with XAMPP individually just for database work? I'm asking this because I have already installed XAMPP and don't want to install mySQL again if the answer of my above question will be YES.

Comment: You can use only the mysql database sever that some with the XAMPP, there is no problem in that, you will just need the start the apache and mysql server in from the Xampp control panel.

Answer (score 0):

That's the simplest answer: Yes!